# Sum sql columns using float(C#)

Tags: c#, sql

I'm using this code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Initial     
Catalog=dbsoft;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(price) FROM fiscal");
cmd.Connection = con;
int sum = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
label3.Text = sum.ToString();
con.Close();
```

i get this error message:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Did i miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sqlcommand.executescalar) returns an object, you have to cast/convert it to your required type. If you are expecting your `SUM` to be of type `float` in DB then use `double` since `float` in SQL server [maps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx) to `double` in C#. like:

```
double sum = (double) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Also consider enclosing your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` object it [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), that will ensure resource disposal, even in case of an exception.

Comment: Still doesnt work.Shoud i use Cast?                                                           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=dbsoft;Integrated Security=True"); 
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(price) FROM fiscal");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            double sum = (double)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            label3.Text = sum.ToString();
            con.Close();

Comment: @DmO, what about if you try `double sum = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar);`

Answer (score 1):

When summing up *prices* like `12.34`, `56.78` etc. we might expect to get *floating point value*. In case of *money*, `Decimal` is a typical choice (instead of `int`):

```
  ...
  // Convert.ToDecimal - let .Net convert, not just cast;
  // what if, say, String has been returned?
  Decimal sum = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); // Decimal sum

  label3.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Implementation:

```
String connString = @"Data Source=(local);Initial     
Catalog=dbsoft;Integrated Security=True";

// Wrap IDisposable into using
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
  con.Open();

  // Wrap IDisposable into using
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    @"SELECT SUM(price) 
        FROM fiscal")) {

    cmd.Connection = con;

    Decimal sum = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); // Decimal sum

    label3.Text = sum.ToString(); 

    // or
    // Shortcut - you have no need in additional convert/cast 
    //label3.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
  }
}
```